# Hide the email address when searching for users

Tags: search

When using the Drupal custom search form, and searching for users (search/user), the user's email address is displayed to administrator users. I want to hide it, even to the administrator users.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is this email normally hidden?

Comment: If you are logged in as administrator, you'll see the email. Normal users should not see it. Try logging in as a regular user if you have not done so already.

Comment: Yes, I already did that. Only being an administrator I am able to see the email of the user. But my requirement is to hide the email from search result list for admin also.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no such an option to hide email addresses from drupal system. You can create your own [search-results.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search-results.tpl.php/7) in your theme or use [`template_preprocess_search_results()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_search_results/7) in your `template.php` to alter the user names.

Answer (score 0):

Only user with the *Administer users* permission are able to search user by email and and view email on user search result. This permission also give them many right like editing the users' profiles, including seeing and editing their email address.

If you really want to grant this permission the some administrative users, allow them the access the other features requiring the *Administer users* permission but hide the email address in the user search results, then implementing [`HOOK_preprocess_search_result()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_search_result/7) (without the 's') in your custom theme or module is a good way to remove the email addresses. In your hook implementation, you will want to remove the email addresses from `$variables['title']` which contains the username followed by the email address. You can retrieve the user object in `$variables['result']['user']` and use `$variables['result']['module'] == 'user'` to check if the result is a user search result.